# remove html tags from a string using RE2 regex library

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I need to remove HTML tags from a string:

```
std::String whole_file("<imgxyz width=139\nheight=82 id=\"_x0000_i1034\" \n src=\"cid:image001.jpg@01CB8C98.EA83E0A0\" \nalign=baseline border=0> \ndfdsf");
```

When I use RE2 library for pattern remove

```
RE2::GlobalReplace(&whole_file,"<.*?>"," ");
```

The Html Tags are not removed, when i use

```
RE2::GlobalReplace(&whole_file,"<.*\n.*\n.*?>"," ");
```

The html tags are removed, why is it so .. can any one suggest a better regular expression to remove HTML tags from a file?

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess: `.` does not match the EOL character.

You could use: `"<[.\n]*?>"` to match any number of newline character.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, played around with the RE2 code and made a mistake, pattern "<.*?>" is sufficient to match.

Comment: RE2::GlobalReplace(&whole_file,"<(.|\n)*?>","");

Comment: You can also seek to avoid backtracking by turning it into `<[^>]+>`

Comment: RE2 library is devoid of back tracking, that's the whole purpose of using it :)

Comment: @Piyush: ah, thanks for letting me know :) I guess it optimized your regex automatically then.

Answer (score 0):

Check pattern: `<[^>]*>`

Sample code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    //Find all html codes
    std::regex htmlCodes("<[^>]*>");
    std::cmatch matches;
    const char* nativeString = "asas<td cl<asas> ass=\"played\">0</td><td class=\"played\">";

    int offset = 0;
    while(std::regex_search ( nativeString + offset, matches, htmlCodes ))
    {
        if(matches.size() < 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (unsigned i=0; i<matches.size(); ++i)
        {
            const int position = matches.position(i) + offset;
            printf("Found: %s %d %ld\n",matches[i].str().c_str(),position,matches.length(i));
            offset = position +  matches.length(i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Found: <td cl<asas> 4 12
Found: </td> 31 5
Found: <td class="played"> 36 19
```